# Why doesn't greedy algorithm work for some currencies that are unlike US currency?

Tags: algorithm, greedy

To make $6.39, you can choose:

- $5 bill
- $1 bill to make $6.
- 25¢ coin, to make $6.25
- 10¢ coin, to make $6.35
- Four 1¢ coins, to make $6.39.

However it doesn't work if the currency has coins with weights of 1,7, and 10. My question is, why does the greedy algorithm work [efficiently] only for a few weights? What are the conditions to be satisfied for the given set of weights to satisfy the greedy algorithm **and** be optimal at the same time?

Comment: What you mean by "efficient"/"optimal" ? Fewest number of operations ? Fewest number of coins in result ? Something else ?

Comment: @PaulR Minimizing the number of coins needed. Do you think I should edit the question details to make it more clear?

Comment: [For those of us **not** extensively familiar with US currency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/US_currency). It might be helpful to summarise this in the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does the greedy coin change algorithm not work for some coin sets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13557979/why-does-the-greedy-coin-change-algorithm-not-work-for-some-coin-sets)

Answer (score 2):

This exact problem is examined in ['A polynomial-time algorithm for the change-making problem' by David Pearson](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.57.3243&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Unfortunately, it doesn't provide an elegant mathematical property that answers the question. It is based on the fact that if the greedy algorithm doesn't work, a counterexample will be among a finite number of values and these values have properties which make it cheap to check each one.

Answer (score 0):

Some answers can be found in this article: http://arxiv.org/pdf/0801.0120v2.pdf

(At least according to their abstract, I didn't read the whole paper)