# I'm writing a program that asks the user to enter a number between 0 and 99, and for my program to calculate the least amount of change (coins)

Tags: c++

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    int num, q, d, n, p;

    cout << "Enter a numner between 0 to 99 for cents: ";
    cin >> num;

    q = num / 25;
    cout << "The number of quarters: " << q << endl;
    d = (num % 25 ) / 10;
    cout << "The number of dimes: " << d << endl;
    n = (num % 10) / 5;
    cout << "The number of nickels: " << n << endl;
    p = (num % 5) / 1;
    cout << "The number of pennies: " << p << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

I entered 78 and my results are:
quarters: 3
dimes: 0
nickels: 1
pennies: 3

Everything is correct except the nickels value. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong for the nickels calculation.[image]

Comment: Please post code, logs, error messages and other text as text, not as image.

Comment: Try to explain how the code you have written ought to execute step-by-step. Then you'll see what the issue is.

Comment: Hint: you need to keep track of the remaining value after some coins are paid.

Comment: Note: there should be a decent [debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2022) with the IDE you're using. Familiarize yourself and start saving yourself time troubleshooting your code.  Basic usage is to set a breakpoint around where you think the bug is (or right at the beginning if you have no clue) and then start stepping, paying close attention for were the program does something you didn't expect like store the wrong value or take the wrong path.

Comment: Examine the aftermath for clues, then either fix the problem or start over and see if you can spot anything unexpected earlier now that you have a better idea of what to look for.

Comment: *calculate the least amount of change (coins)* -- Even if you got what you intended to work, the answer you accepted is not going to get you the least number of coins that can be used to make change for all inputs.

Comment: What county's coinage is this?  The coloquial terms suggest USA, but that has a 50c coin (Half Dollar) also.

Comment: [See this information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13557979/why-does-the-greedy-coin-change-algorithm-not-work-for-some-coin-sets).

Comment: Definitely not Canada. We nuked the penny years ago. But we make up for it with 1 and 2 dollar coins.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue and debug your program, but my IDE doesn't accept images.  My compilers didn't accept them either.  No programs posted as text == no help.

Comment: Pretty sure I see code-as-text above the image.

Comment: @user4581301 They just wanted to ensure SO kept its reputation of being toxic and unfriendly is all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to update `num` after each calculation to reduce its amount by the value of the coins you just calculated, so that the next calculation is done on the adjusted amount that is left over.

With the way you are doing it right now, you are calculating the number of nickels and pennies that are in the *original* amount, not in the *adjusted* amount, which is why you are getting the wrong results.

IOW, after you calculated the number of quarters, you ignored the value of the quarters when calculating the number of dimes, but you did not subsequently ignore the value of the dimes before calculating the number of nickels, or ignore the value of the nickels before calculating the number of pennies.

Try this instead:

```
q = num / 25;
num %= 25; // <-- add this!
cout << "The number of quarters: " << q << endl;
d = num / 10;
num %= 10; // <-- add this!
cout << "The number of dimes: " << d << endl;
n = num / 5;
num %= 5; // <-- add this!
cout << "The number of nickels: " << n << endl;
p = num / 1;
cout << "The number of pennies: " << p << endl;
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/GaUnsP)

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I see why I experienced the issue that I did and have made a not and change of it.

Comment: @Jermal *calculate the least amount of change (coins)* -- Is the goal to get the least number of coins?  I don't think this code gets the least number of coins -- it does give you the number of quarters, dimes, etc., but to get the least number of coins requires a little more sophistication.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: I think that for the values 25/10/5/1, the least quarters/dimes/etc and the least number of coins is the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

At each stage, the calculation should be performed on the remainder, not the whole original sum.  For example after:

```
q = num / 25;
```

You need to update `num` thus:

```
num -= q * 25 ;
```